# Count array key that contain specific string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array like that contain key with same name but with number at the end

array example:

```
Array
(
    [field_name0] => name 
    [field_name1] => sku_package_height 
    [field_name2] => sku_package_width
    [custom_field] => 13
    [attribute] => 'test'
    [field_name3] => sku_package_length 
    [field_name4] => sku_package_weight
)
```

from the example above i want to count how many record that has array key that contain `field_name`, so the result I want will be `5`

Comment: can you update your question with the actual php array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php
$original_array = Array
(
    'field_name0' => 'name',
    'field_name1' => 'sku_package_height',
    'field_name2' => 'sku_package_width',
    'custom_field' => 13,
    'attribute' => 'test',
    'field_name3' => 'sku_package_length',
    'field_name4' => 'sku_package_weight'
);
$search = "field_name";
$counter = 0;
foreach($original_array as $key=> $value){
    if(strstr($key,$search)){
       $counter = $counter+1;
    }
}

echo $counter;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/704506

Or

```
<?php
$original_array = Array
(
    'field_name0' => 'name',
    'field_name1' => 'sku_package_height',
    'field_name2' => 'sku_package_width',
    'custom_field' => 13,
    'attribute' => 'test',
    'field_name3' => 'sku_package_length',
    'field_name4' => 'sku_package_weight',
);
$search = "field_name";
$counter = 0;
foreach($original_array as $key=> $value){
    if(is_numeric(strpos($key,$search))){
       $counter = $counter+1;
    }
}

echo $counter;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/704518

Comment: I think strpos should be used like this : `strpos($keys_arr,$search)`! am I right?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :

```
$count = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value){

   if(strpos($key,"field_name") > -1){
      $count++;
   }

}
```

`$count` will have number of keys.

Comment: the result is 0

Comment: let me test it!

Comment: try this `strpos($key,"field_name") > -1` . updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Check the isnumeric of the string position "field_name" in key

```
$i= 0;
foreach($arrayfields as $keys => $values){

   if (is_numeric(strpos($keys,"field_name"))){
      $i++;
   }

}
echo $i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array=array("field_name0"=>"name","field_name1"=>"sku_package_height ","field_name2"=>"sku_package_width","custom_field"=>"13","attribute"=>"test","field_name3"=>"sku_package_length", "field_name4"=>"sku_package_weight");

echo  $arraykey= count(preg_grep("/^field_name(\d)+$/",array_keys($array)));
?>
```

Comment: the result is 0

Comment: you have to replay $array with your variable  here -> array_keys($array)

Comment: checkout updated version you should idea what i'm trying to say